# Ordinary guns in space

Tags: space, weapons

Can you kill someone from an ordinary gun in space? Will it be able to shoot?

I mean weapons like M4A1, pistols, rifles, shotguns, machine guns.

How will they behave in open space?

My thoughts are these: because there is no air, gravity and tension then the bullets either won't fly out or they will just glide through space without much force to penetrate anything. So definitely guns and bullets won't work in space.

Comment: Research..... I mean honestly, what makes you think this would/should not work?

Comment: Also, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/how-can-i-create-explosions-without-using-oxygen/89577#89577 explains why they would normally still work. I'm also pretty sure this is a dupe of a question that was asked better on this site, I just can't find it right now.

Comment: The main issue with using firearms in space is vacuum welding of the components, and differential expansion of the metal and plastic parts exposed to direct sunlight or being in shadow, preventing the mechanical parts of the gun from working. The rounds will fire normally and have the same effect.

Comment: Has this ever been tried in real life?

Comment: Yes, a Soviet era military "Almaz" space station, operating under the cover name "Salut 3", was armed with a 23 or 30mm aircraft cannon. The weapon was remotely test fired by the ground controllers when the station was unmanned.

Answer (score 4):

It will shoot, and its bullets will be just as deadly (or if the targets life support depends on a space suit that can be punctured, even more deadly). However the recoil can have unexpected effects on the bearer: In weightlessness, if he/she is not fastened to something, he/she will float away and spin up, making repeated shooting much harder.

Comment: @TimBII Explosives do not require external air: they contain oxidiser, saltpeter for example in the case of black powder. Torpedoes and mines can explode underwater...

Comment: @TimBII In addtition to what b.Lorenz wrote: most modern ammonitions use nitrocellulose, which has also its own oxidiser

Comment: @TimBII see https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/how-can-i-create-explosions-without-using-oxygen/89577#89577